# Trying to do a POST call for an SDK connecting to JSONAPI

Tags: c#, api, sdk, json-api

I'm trying to create an SDK to connect for an API done with jsonapi (https://jsonapi.org/) , however I'm having problems trying to do POST request.
I have some GET calls, but I don't know howe to implement the POST. is there any examples I could see? (I couldn't find in the documentation)

I have for GET:

```
public async Task<Clinic[]> GetClinicsAsync(int page = 1)
        {
            var uri = $"api/api-clinics".AddQueryParams(new Dictionary<string, string?> {
                                                ["page"] = page.ToString(),
                                            }
            );

            return await _http.SendAsyncInternal<Clinic[]>(HttpMethod.Get, uri, new Dictionary<string, string>()) ?? Array.Empty<Clinic>();
        }
```

with an interface like this:

/// Get the list of clinics.

```
Task<Clinic[]> GetClinicsAsync(int page);
```

but form the example I have for a post I have this:

```
https://journalapi.website.de/api/api-bookings?caregiver_id=43&patient_personal_id=435496
PAYLOAD {"data":{"attributes":{"booked_by_patient":true,"class":"PUBLIC","description":"description text","dtend":"2022-03-09T10:00:00+01:00","dtstamp":"2022-03-08T08:10:27+01:00","dtstart":"2022-03-09T09:30:00+01:00","location":"1231, 31311 3131","new_patient":true,"referral_source":"","status":"CONFIRMED","summary":"summary text","text":"","transp":"OPAQUE","uid":null,"first_name":"","last_name":"","e_mail_address":"","phone_number_cell":""},"relationships":{"clinic":{"data":{"id":"2312","type":"api-clinics"}},"organizer":{"data":{"id":"5553","type":"api-caregivers"}},"procedure":{"data":{"id":"1","type":"api-procedure"}}},"type":"api-bookings"},"include":"booking_attendees.patient"}
```

I don't know how this payload should be dealt with:

```
     public async Task CreateBookingAsync(string clinicId, string caregiverId, string procedureId, string id,
            DateTimeOffset start, DateTimeOffset end)
        {
            var uri = "api/api-bookings".AddQueryParams(new Dictionary<string, string?> {
                                                ["caregiver_id"] = caregiverId,
                                                ["patient_personal_id"] = id
                                            }
            );

            var body = new DocumentRoot<BookingRequest>();

            body.Included = new List<JObject> { new JObject("test") };
}
```

Edit: adding attempt:

```
public async Task<string> CreateBookingAsync(string clinicId,  string procedureId, string swedishPersonalIdentityNumber,
            DateTimeOffset start, DateTimeOffset end, Booking booking)
        {
            var uri = "api/api-bookings".AddQueryParams(new Dictionary<string, string?> {
                                                ["caregiver_id"] = clinicId,
                                                ["patient_personal_id"] = swedishPersonalIdentityNumber
                                            }
            );

            var jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(booking);
            var content = new StringContent(jsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var response = _http.PostAsync(uri, content).Result;

            var body = new DocumentRoot<BookingRequest>
            {
                Included = new List<JObject> { new JObject("test") }
            };

            return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
```

Comment: Are you having problems de-serializing the response? Or are you having problems serializing your data for your `POST` request?

Comment: I don't entirely understand how should I send the data to the post, how to serialize it into that "payload" object

Comment: What parameters do you require to `POST` to your `API`? Can you show us that `Model` or structure that you want to post?

Comment: the information that I have is from the url for booking example, the model I want to post is based on the example call provided, I have "caregiver_id", "patient_personal_id",  and then that PAYLOAD section, which I don't know if I should model entirely as an object or is something I'm not getting there. (my issue comes from setting up the POST object model with that Payload

Comment: calling that url POST a booking, so I need to understand how to set a POST call from that url

Comment: Did you get this working @Baldie47?

Comment: @RahulSharma no :( I'm still trying to get it to work, I can do the GET calls, but the POST is failing, I don't know how to set the Payload

Comment: Ok, Can you post more code on your attempt? Did you try doing it as I explained in my answer @Baldie47

Comment: yes, I'll add an edit

Comment: What error are you getting on this line: `var response = _http.PostAsync(uri, content).Result;` ? @Baldie47

Comment: Can you post the endpoint method `api-bookings`. I think there is a mismatch in the payload request that you are sending and what the method is expecting @Baldie47

Comment: Yes. I was able to advance some. Please check here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71498656/json-self-referencing-loop-on-post-call/71499635?noredirect=1#comment126374262_71499635

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In its simplest terms, you can make `POST` call to your API by first serializing your `Model` and then sending it to your endpoint.

Your `Model` will look like based on your input:

```
public class PayloadData
{  
    public string caregiver_id {get;set;}
    public string patient_personal_id {get;set;}
}
```

Your call will look something like this:

```
public async Task CreateBookingAsync(string clinicId, string caregiverId, string procedureId, string id, DateTimeOffset start, DateTimeOffset end)
{
    PayloadData data=new PayloadData();
    data.caregiver_id=caregiverId
    data.patient_personal_id=id
    var uri = "api/api-bookings";
    string jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
    StringContent content = new StringContent(jsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    HttpResponseMessage response = _http.PostAsync(uri, content).Result;
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
      var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
      //Deserialize your result as required
      //var myFinalData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(result);
    }

    //Your logic
}
```