# JSON Self referencing loop on POST call

Tags: c#, json, api, json-api, jsonapi-serialize

I'm trying to send a POST call via JsonApi with this as example:

```
{
    "data": {
        "attributes": {
            "booked_by_patient": true,
            "class": "PUBLIC",
            "description": "description",
            "dtend": "2022-03-16T10:30:00+01:00",
            "dtstamp": "2022-03-16T10:01:17+01:00",
            "dtstart": "2022-03-16T10:00:00+01:00",
            "location": "1231, 31311 3131",
            "new_patient": true,
            "referral_source": "",
            "status": "CONFIRMED",
            "summary": "summary",
            "text": "",
            "transp": "OPAQUE",
            "uid": null,
            "first_name": "name",
            "last_name": "last_name",
            "e_mail_address": "email@domain.com",
            "phone_number_cell": "+467325324563252"
        },
        "relationships": {
            "clinic": {
                "data": {
                    "id": "2312",
                    "type": "Pizza-clinics"
                }
            },
            "organizer": {
                "data": {
                    "id": "5553",
                    "type": "Pizza-caregivers"
                }
            },
            "procedure": {
                "data": {
                    "id": "1",
                    "type": "Pizza-procedure"
                }
            }
        },
        "type": "Pizza-bookings"
    },
    "include": "booking_attendees.patient"
}
```

But for starters, I'm getting an error for "Self referencing loop detected for property 'data' with type 'SDKs.Pizza.Model.Clinics'. Path 'data.clinic.data'.

following another suggestion I received that I needed to add a [JsonIgnore] decorator over some models, I have done the following: (decorator over 3 last objects)

```
public class BookingRequest 
    {
        // public string Id { get; set; }
        public string? Uid { get; set; } = null;

        public string Type { get; } = "pizza_bookings";

        public bool BookedByPatient { get; set; } = true;

        public string Class { get; set; } = "PUBLIC";

        public string Description { get; set; } = null!;
        
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "dtstart")]
        public DateTimeOffset Start { get; set; }
        
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "dtend")]
        public DateTimeOffset End { get; set; }
        
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "dtstamp")]
        public DateTimeOffset Timestamp { get; set; } = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;

        public string EMailAddress { get; set; } = null!;

        public string FirstName { get; set; } = null!;

        public string LastName { get; set; } = null!;

        public string Location { get; set; } = null!;

        public bool NewPatient { get; set; } = true;

        public string PhoneNumberCell { get; set; } = null!;

        public string ReferralSource { get; set; } = "source";

        public string Status { get; set; } = "CONFIRMED";

        public string Summary { get; set; } = "";

        public string Text { get; set; } = "";

        public string? Transp { get; set; } = "OPAQUE";

        [JsonIgnore]
        public Relationship<Clinics> Clinic { get; set; } = null!;
        [JsonIgnore]
        public Relationship<Caregivers> Organizer { get; set; } = null!;
        [JsonIgnore]
        public Relationship<Procedures> Procedure { get; set; } = null!;
    }
```

My current POST call is as follows:

```cs
public async Task<Booking?> CreateBookingAsync(string clinicId, string caregiverId, string procedureId, string ssn,
            DateTimeOffset start, DateTimeOffset end)
        {
            var uri = "api/pizza-bookings".AddQueryParams(new Dictionary<string, string?> {
                                                ["caregiver_id"] = caregiverId,
                                                ["patient_personal_id"] = swedishPersonalIdentityNumber
                                            }
            );

            var body = new DocumentRoot<BookingRequest>();

            var clinic = new Relationship<Clinics>() {Data = new Clinics() {Id = clinicId}};

            var organizer = new Relationship<Caregivers>() {Data = new Caregivers() {Id = caregiverId}};

            var procedure = new Relationship<Procedures>() {Data = new Procedures() {Id = procedureId}};

            body.Data = new BookingRequest() {
                Start = start,
                End = end,
                EMailAddress = "email@domain.com",
                PhoneNumberCell = "123-456-789",
                FirstName = "first-name",
                LastName = "last-name",
                Clinic = clinic,
                Organizer = organizer,
                Procedure = procedure
            };

            return await _http.SendInternalAsync<DocumentRoot<BookingRequest>, Booking>(HttpMethod.Post, uri, body, new Dictionary<string, string>());
            }
```

the issue that I have here is that if I add the jsonIgnore the code runs, but the JSON I capture from Fiddler is the following:

```
{
    "data": {
        "type": "pizza_bookings",
        "bookedByPatient": true,
        "class": "PUBLIC",
        "dtstart": "2022-03-17T08:56:00+01:00",
        "dtend": "2022-03-17T09:26:00+01:00",
        "dtstamp": "2022-03-17T07:56:48.3039336+00:00",
        "eMailAddress": "email@domain.com",
        "firstName": "first-name",
        "lastName": "last-name",
        "newPatient": true,
        "phoneNumberCell": "123-456-789",
        "referralSource": "source",
        "status": "CONFIRMED",
        "summary": "",
        "text": "",
        "transp": "OPAQUE",
        "clinic": {
            "data": {}
        },
        "organizer": {
            "data": {}
        },
        "procedure": {
            "data": {}
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ignore the self-referencing loops while serializing by using `ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore` which will not serialize an object if it is a child object of itself. You can use it by adding it in your serializer settings:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body.Data, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings { ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore});
```

Comment: yes, I don't have the self referencing loop anymore, I'm having an issue that I think it's particular to JsonAPI or the library github.com/codecutout/JsonApiSerializer

Comment: @Baldie47 What is the current issue in question?

Comment: the reference loop doesn't happen anymore, but the POST is not having the format that it should, in the first section of this post I'm showing how it is supposed to be, but in the last block I'm showing what I'm sending from the fiddle trace